# Combining values in 2 rows of a list without duplicating in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops

Let's say i have 6 rows in a list, all rows have string data. For example :

```
samplelist=['Hi. This is a sample list.', '', 'just trying',
            'to get my code work', 'Please help', '']
```

As you can see, some rows are followed by empty rows while one has a string following it.

If the row following the string is empty, i need to append that row [non-null] into another list.

If the row following the string is not empty, i need to combine the two rows `[string1+string2]` and append into a list.

The final list should not have any duplicates. I am trying to get this done but not able to! Do let me know if you are able to solve it!

Comment: Hi there. What is your expected output (specifically, with the data you have)? Verbal description is helpful but it will *really really* help us if you can provide what you expect to obtain as a final result.

Comment: expected=['Hi. This is a sample list.','just trying to get my code work','Please help']

Comment: What I have posted above is the result I am looking for. Ignore the blanks [''] but if there is any info, append into the previous row.

Comment: Why aren't "to get my code work" and "Please help" merged? And why is there a space between "trying" and "to"?

Comment: You can use reduce to create paragraphes. The bigger question is how did you get this format anyway? if you split on newline maybe you should split on two newlines?

Comment: @DYZ,  So the data i pulled out is in a text format. There are multiple files and the location of the white spaces are inconsistent. The format i wanted was that if second row was not blank, attach that value to the row prior to it. If the second row is blank, save it as it is to the new list. So when the loop reaches the first row, it should check second row value, which is null here. So it should save 'Hi. This is a sample list.' as it is. When it reaches the second row, which is blank, loop should continue.

Comment: When it reaches the third row, which is not blank, it checks the 4th which is not blank. So it attaches 4th row to the third and result will be 'just trying to get my code work'. Since 4th row has been attached to the third, it should continue at 4th row value and loop should reach row 5. At this point, it should check row 6 which is blank. Hence it will save the 5th row as it is,  'Please help'. Hope this makes it clear.